# Why can't I prepare the serializer with a struct?

Tags: protobuf-net

Protobuf-Net 2.0.0.480 can serialize structs using either the `DataContract` or `ProtoContract` attribute, and is doing so just fine.

However, `Serializer.PrepareSerializer<MyStruct>()` claims that `MyStruct` must be a reference type. Why does this limitation exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fair observation! This is a hangover from v1, where the API only supported `class`. The v2 implementation adds `RuntimeTypeModel`, and forwards the old `Serializer.*` API onto `RuntimeTypeMode.Default.*`.

In this case, the answer is simple: because I didn't remove the `where T : class` constraint that existed from v1 days. It will be removed in a future build.

For now, you can also do this via:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default[type].CompileInPlace();
```

Comment: I was curious if it was a simple leftover constraint from v1! Thanks for the temporary workaround.